# How to override latex template commands?

Tags: theorems, templates

Using the template https://www.overleaf.com/articles/an-initial-analysis-of-approximation-error-for-evolutionary-algorithms/kgkpjgxzywjq
and I was wondering if I could override the theorem style set in the template to the ams style without having to modify the .sty file?

Comment: Since theorems are defined as a `newenviroment` in this template, you can always change things with `renewenviroment`, you can see something about that in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Environments. Of course, you will need to use beamer commands as in the original definition

Comment: what have you tried? there is nothing in latex really called a "template" it's just an example document, you'd expect to load amsthm and define some environments. If you get an error ask about the error.

Comment: The .tex document linked to is a beamer poster and uses a custom package, `aber`, which is what presumably defines the `greenblock` environment. There looks to be nothing special about the theorems etc inside - they are probably customised `tcolobox`es, from the looks of the formatting. (see `tcolorbox` package). Alternatively, the author of the document might be worthwhile contacting, especially as to the contents of `aber`.

Comment: @Cicada  Actually what I meant was is it possible to put something in the preamble that effectively says actually ovveride the .sty file and do theorems using ams style   that is numbered automatically?

To be honest, the more I think the more I'm not sure it's actually a good idea to do that but I would like to know how.